# async.eachLimit executes only for the limit specified and not the whole array

Tags: node.js, npm, async.js

I am using npm async library (https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) to limit the number of parallel requests.
Below is my code :

```
    async.eachLimit(listOfItemIds, 10, function(itemId)
    {
      console.log("in with item Id: ",itemId);
    }, function(err) {
         if(err) 
         {
           console.log("err : ",err);
           throw err;
         }
    });
```

But it does not execute for all the listOfItemIds, it only executes for the first 10 and exits.

Below is the output :

```
in with item id:  252511893899
in with item id:  142558907839
in with item id:  273235013353
in with item id:  112966379563
in with item id:  192525382704
in with item id:  253336093614
in with item id:  112313616389
in with item id:  162256230991
in with item id:  282981461384
in with item id:  263607905569
```

Comment: Sorry about the console.log statement : it is supposed to be console.log("in with item id: ",itemId)

Comment: @Rashika can you also post the npm library package link here.

Comment: There is limit given in second parameter, increase it to what you think will include all. Here `async.eachLimit(listOfItemIds, ` **10** `, function(itemId)`.

Comment: Or if you want to reach some sort of limit you could do math with the length of list items. Such as `listOfItemIds.length - 10` or  to get roughly half `Math.floor(listOfItemIds.length / 2)`. Then use that as the second argument.

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass along a callback() method as well.

Here have a look at the code below, this will work.

```
async.eachLimit(listOfItemIds, 2, function(itemId, callback)
{
  console.log("in with item Id: ",itemId);
  callback();
}, function(err) {
      if(err) 
      {
        console.log("err : ",err);
        throw err;
      }
});
```

This will print all the elements in the array, I have limit the number of parallel executions to be `2` in the above case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the perfect solution!

Comment: By the way you can mark my answer, it will be useful for future references.

Comment: You could use async functions so when they finish, async continues.

```async.eachLimit(listOfItemIds, 10, async function(itemId)
    {
      console.log("in with item Id: ",itemId);
    }, function(err) {
         if(err) 
         {
           console.log("err : ",err);
           throw err;
         }
    });
```

Comment: For some reason even with async I was required to provide a callback!